# Synchronize multiple application

Tags: delphi, synchronization

I have multiple services processing some files. Each service must have exclusive access to the file while processing. I solved this problem a while ago by creating a global mutex that uses some temp files, something like this:

```
function AppLocked: boolean;
begin
  result := FileExists(GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt);
end;

procedure AppLock;
var
  F: TextFile;
begin
  if FileExists(GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt) then
    exit
  else
  try
    AssignFile(F, GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt);
    Rewrite(F);
    Writeln(F, DateTimeToStr(Now));
    CloseFile(F);
  except
  end;
end;

procedure AppUnLock;
begin
  if FileExists(GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt) then
    SysUtils.DeleteFile(GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt);
end;
```

This works pretty good, and I don't want to fix something that works, but I just wonder, is there a better solution?

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? There is a fairly good example of inter-process communication included with Delphi versions at least through D2007 (in the Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\IPCDemos folder); in more recent versions, there's the Samples\Delphi\RTL\SimpleShareMem demo.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE. I found the example and I'm studying it right now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point, 'Rewrite' will already fail for another process unless the process that opened the file closes it.

Comment: If you try to open a file for exclusive access and it fails, you know the file is in use so just skip it and try again later. No need to synchronize between the processes using a mutex, etc at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An actual Mutex (as in win32 Mutex) is the preferred method.

Comment: This is not an answer; it's a question or suggestion, and should be posted as a comment instead. If you want it to be an answer, you need to add content to make it one, and phrase it as an answer instead of a question.

Comment: Well, originally, before I started using temp files as mutex, I tried using win global mutex, but *if I remember right*, there were some versions of windows where I had problems. Some of the code I use I wrote it when the windows NT was around... and, if I remember right, on some machines with some version of windows, the global mutex wasn't global (at least I couldn't make it work)... so I decided to use files. Probably I should give win32 mutex another try?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has a problem, if the application terminates and you missed to unlock. This could happen on an abnormal termination. It would be better to create a file, that will automatically erase itself if the application terminates.

All the magic is done by [FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
unit uAppLock;

interface

function AppLocked : Boolean;
function AppLock : Boolean;
procedure AppUnlock;

implementation

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes;

var
  // unit global variable 
  LockFileHandle : THandle;

// function to build the filename
function GetLockFileName : string;
begin
  // You have to point out, where to get these informations
  Result := GetTempDir + '__MUTEX__' + LockExt;
end;

function AppLocked : Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists( GetLockFileName );
end;

function AppLock : Boolean;
var
  LFileName :       string;
  LLockFileStream : TStream;
  LInfoStream :     TStringStream;
begin
  Result := False;

  if AppLock
  then
    Exit;

  LFileName := GetLockFileName;

  // Retrieve the handle of the LockFile
  LockFileHandle := CreateFile( PChar( LFileName ), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    nil, CREATE_NEW, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, 0 );

  if LockFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
  then
    begin

      Result := True;

      LInfoStream     := nil;
      LLockFileStream := nil;
      try

        LInfoStream := TStringStream.Create;
        LInfoStream.WriteString( DateTimeToStr( Now ) );
        LInfoStream.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );

        LLockFileStream := THandleStream.Create( LockFileHandle );
        LLockFileStream.CopyFrom( LInfoStream, LInfoStream.Size );

      finally
        LInfoStream.Free;
        LLockFileStream.Free;
      end;

    end;

end;

procedure AppUnlock;
begin
  // Just close the handle and the file will be deleted
  CloseHandle( LockFileHandle );
end;

end.
```

BTW: **GetTempDir** looks to be a Directory, but you use it as a Path. So it would be better to rename it into **GetTempPath** instead :o)

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good advice. I'll keep that in mind in the situation I'll have to still use files as mutex. Right now I'm testing the TMutex and so far so good.